Get a screenshot of the screen using libpipewire
Is it possible to use libpipewire to get the current screen picture? I looked at the example https://docs.pipewire.org/page_tutorial5.html, but I understand that it's capturing video from a camera. And another question: in what form libpipewire gives the captured video/screenshots, i.e. how to get, for example, a png/jpg picture of the screen? Any examples and links would be appreciated.

Hi ibse. I'm struggling with screenshots on Wayland. Someone had voted your question down, which I have negated by voting it up. It is a good question. OBS Studio uses pipewire for screencapture. I see no reason you can't use pipewire to get a screenshot.

I've found this guide:
https://onexception.dev/news/1287960/libpipewire-screenshot-guide
And here is a link to the PipeWire doco:
https://docs.pipewire.org/page_tutorial.html
